# How to connect to MySql using Entity Framework 6 from an ASP.NET 5 Web API application?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dnx

I have a Web API project created in ASP.NET 5 which uses the dnx451 framework. The project uses Entity Framework 6.1.3 and MySql .NET connector (MySql.Data.Entity) version 6.9.7 to connect to a MySql database.

Since there is no web.config, I need to use code based configuration to connect to the database. But I have run up against problems here.

I have a DbConfiguration implementation to handle the configuration. I followed the example mentioned here: http://dan.cx/2015/08/entity-framework-6-mysql-aspnet

However, I get a compilation error at this line:

var dataSet = (DataSet)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data");

The error is: 
"Using the generic type 'ConfigurationManager' requires 1 type arguments".

Not sure what type argument I should pass in there.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it ! Just import "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final" in your project.json ;)